# How to embed Expo Snacks in Stack Overflow?

Tags: react-native, expo

I would like to embed [Expo Snacks](https://snack.expo.io/) in a Stack Overflow question or answer, is it possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you click the button for "JavaScript/HTML/CSS Snippet" on the Stack Overflow editing toolbar, you can paste the embed code from Snack into the HTML box. This will create a runnable code snippet in your question or response, and when run the code snippet will show the Snack embed frame. It's a bit truncated but it works, and it also provides a link to open in Snack itself.

You can see an example of this with the snippet I've embedded into my answer.

```html
<div data-snack-id="B10gXLb4b" data-snack-platform="ios" data-snack-preview="true" data-snack-theme="dark" style="overflow:hidden;background:#212733;border:1px solid rgba(0,0,0,.16);border-radius:4px;height:505px;width:100%"></div>
<script async src="https://snack.expo.io/embed.js"></script>
```

Comment: Didn't seem to work. I clicked "Run code snippet" above and was greeted with a blank screen. I also tried embedding an Expo Snack myself and got the same blank screen.

Comment: how is this the accepted answer when it does not work? did it work before?